# Server 2012 Cluster - Second Node Can't Ping Items

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster

I've got a server 2012 SQL Cluster and all of the processes failover and run properly. The only odd behavior is that when I fail over to the secondary node, there are certain items on one NIC that can't seem to be pinged by the secondary node. When the primary node is up, I can ping the virtual IP for that NIC just fine, so that NIC has connectivity. The other NICs can ping their respective devices just fine, but this one seems to be behaving oddly. I have seen this with two setups of the same configuration as well.

The network side is just a layer 2 switch, but no Vlans have been applied, so it's basically one big vlan for all of the NICs.

So the problem is that there's an application that runs that talks to devices on that problematic network. Since there's no ping available, there's no traffic, so none of those devices are able to come up on the secondary node. Fail back to the primary and all problems are solved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ping isn't a cluster or SQL Server validation tool. What's the actual network problem you're having?

Comment: Incorrect. As I stated, this is a SQL Cluster, so items fail over between the hosts (such as the virtual IP for the public/private cluster NICs). So devices should be able to ping back and forth from/to both hosts.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue, however the issue got solved when I stopped anti-virus installed in the server from services level.if you have any anti-virus please stop the anti-virus and check whether the issue gets resolved.